# Need help in binomial question and in understanding the reason for nΣk=0 changing

Tags: binomial-theorem

[image]

why exactly does in this question (i and ii) in the answer sheet k=0 turn to k=1 after differentiating and also why does multiplying by (1+x^2) does the 1 expansion keep k=1 and but the x^2 expansion changes it back to k=0

sorry if this is a really easy question or something just due to the nature of my lack of knowledge, i dont even know the right terminology to even begin searching for an answer. all my friends dont know either.

Comment: When $k=0$ you have $C_n^0x^0=1.$ What is the derivative of a constant?

Comment: alright thank you very much so basically the term = 0 for k=0 so it doesnt exist and the new first term is k=1, but why does it change back to k=0 when multiplied by x^2?

Comment: There is no reason for that. Note that when $k=0$ it is $k ^nC_kx^{2k+1}=0\cdot 1\cdot x=0.$

Comment: so if im not mistaken it should start at k=1 not k=0 for that general term?

Comment: You're right. For $k=0$ the corresponding term is $0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following I use the notation $\binom{n}{k}:={}^{n}C_k$.

After differentiation (and division by $2$) the multiplication with $1+x^2$ gives
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n k\binom{n}{k}x^{2k-1}(1+x^2)=\sum_{k=0}^n k\binom{n}{k}x^{2k-1}+\sum_{k=0}^n k\binom{n}{k}x^{2k+1}
\end{align*}

> Note that
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n k \binom{n}{k}x^{2k-1}&=0+\sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k}x^{2k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k}x^{2k-1}\\
> \qquad\qquad\text{and}\\
> \sum_{k=0}^n k \binom{n}{k}x^{2k+1}&=0+\sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k}x^{2k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k}x^{2k+1}
> \end{align*}
>   So, both sums can be written  with index $k$ starting from $k=0$ as well as $k=1$. It's just a matter of convenience and you can choose whatever you prefer.

In fact  I recommend to start both sums with the same starting value either $0$ or $1$ just to simplify reading.